# Shift x-axis to arbitrary position

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code, which draws the d3.js scatterplot. My question is how to shift the x-axis to arbitrary position (e.g., red line in the attached figure below). In other words I wonder how to translate the origin of the coordinate system.

```
var data = [[5,3], [10,17], [15,4], [2,8]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
  .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('class', 'chart')

var main = chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'main')   

    // draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
  .attr("r", 8);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your y scale:

```
main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + y(6) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(xAxis);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [[5,3], [10,17], [15,4], [2,8]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
  .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('class', 'chart')

var main = chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'main')   

    // draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + y(6) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'x axis date')
    .call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .attr('class', 'y axis date')
    .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
  .attr("r", 8);

d3.selectAll(".x .tick").filter(function (d) { return d === 0;  }).remove();
```

```css
.axis path, .axis line {
    opacity: 1;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #4e5a64;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```